# Repeating Many-To-Many Relations

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have one entity **Order** and one entity **Product**.

It should be possible to add one product several times to an order, but with Doctrines default *many-to-many-relation* there can be *only one* relation in the *join-table*. Is there a way to solve this *without an extra entity* and *two one-to-many-relations*?

Answer (score 3):

Why add a Product many times to an Order?  Make it a many-to-many relation with a Quantity column added to it.  One Product with a Quantity of N should satisfy your wish.

Comment: but in which entity would you put the quantity value?

Comment: It would have to be a separate entity.  You'd reify the JOIN table, like a ReportCard for a JOIN between Students and Courses.  See below - I would prefer Oliver Watkins' solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need an OrderLine table. Many-to-Many can exist conceptually, but in a relational database you can't. You have to break it into two Many-to-one relationships

Comment: Right, one-to-many between Order and OrderItem; one-to-one between OrderItem and Product.  OrderItem might have Quantity as a column.  I would prefer a design like this, too.

Comment: one-to-MANY between OrderItem and Product. A product can be involved in more than one order. Yes Quantity would go in the OrderItem table :)

Comment: I disagree - a Product can end up in multiple Orders, but only one OrderItem.  Your OrderItem and mine can refer to the same Product, but they're owned by Order entries that are unique to each of us.

Comment: but what if I have an order for iPAD for Jim in China, and an order for iPAD for Bob in America. My OrderItem table would have two rows which would have a FK referencing the Product Row.

Comment: but i can have different quantities so Product to OrderItem should be one to many?